# Selecting attributes corresponding to the most frequent entries in a junction table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently am writing a query which retrieves the max amount of rows for a junction table.  I'll use the following [example in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/22c5e/1):

> MyTable
>
> ```
> ┌─────────┬─────────┐
> │ a_field │ b_field │
> ├─────────┼─────────┤
> │ a       │ 1       │
> │ b       │ 2       │
> │ c       │ 3       │
> └─────────┴─────────┘
> ```
>
> JunctionTable
>
> ```
> ┌─────────┬──────────────────┐
> │ a_field │ irrelevant_field │
> ├─────────┼──────────────────┤
> │ a       │ z                │
> │ a       │ y                │
> │ a       │ x                │
> │ b       │ z                │
> │ b       │ y                │
> │ b       │ x                │
> │ c       │ z                │
> └─────────┴──────────────────┘
> ```

Note that in the `JunctionTable`, `'a'` and `'b'` are both the most frequent.  I want my query to retrieve `'1'` and `'2'`, which are the corresponding values to `'a'` and `'b'` in `MyTable`.

---

A naïve version of the query would rely on the fact that the ordering is done on the amount and then limits it on 1 to get the max value:

> ```
> SELECT b_field
> FROM MyTable
> WHERE a_field IN (
>     SELECT a_field
>     FROM JunctionTable
>     GROUP BY a_field
>     ORDER BY COUNT(a_field) DESC
>     LIMIT 1
> );
> ```

---

What I want to do, though, is retrieve *both* `'a'` and `'b'` without increasing the LIMIT keyword. To achieve this, I can do the following:

```
SELECT b_field
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a_field, COUNT(a_field) AS amount
    FROM JunctionTable
    GROUP BY a_field
) JC ON JC.a_field = MyTable.a_field
WHERE amount = (
    SELECT MAX(amount)
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(a_field) AS amount
        FROM JunctionTable
        GROUP BY a_field
    ) JC2
);
```

However this screams bad practice to me. Are there any better solutions to this problem?

Comment: I see you have anonymized the query code pretty heavily; would you mind to use the actual object names? We can still review your code as is but it is better to include the real names for context.

Comment: @Phrancis I could, but the names actually won't make very much sense as they are in the first place in dutch and secondly not really self describing, such as JunctionTable and MyTable. However, I am currently creating a SQL Fiddle to simulate the situation.

Comment: @engineercoding Naming is, famously, one of the hardest things in programming. The names not being very descriptive is exactly the kind of thing potential answerers  might offer advice on. Unless you have a specific preference not to post them on the internet, please do put them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that this expression is almost repeated:

> ```
> SELECT a_field, COUNT(a_field) AS amount
>     FROM JunctionTable
>     GROUP BY a_field
> ```

That is an indication that you could use a *Common Table Expression*.  Given the limited information I have about your situation, I would call it `JunctionCount`.  I would rename `amount`, which is ambiguous, to `occurrences`.

To obtain all junctions that have the maximal number of occurrences, you can use the `RANK()` window function.

```
WITH JunctionCount AS (
    SELECT a_field, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
        FROM JunctionTable
        GROUP BY a_field
), MostJunctions AS (
    SELECT a_field, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY occurrences DESC) AS occurrence_rank
        FROM JunctionCount
) SELECT b_field
    FROM MyTable
        INNER JOIN MostJunctions
            ON MyTable.a_field = MostJunctions.a_field
    WHERE MostJunctions.occurrence_rank = 1;
```